# How to access to Home component even though not logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have created certain components which have access only when logged in or else would be redirected to Login Page. While I was told to make few changes that are, the user should have access to the Home page even though not logged in. For accessing other components, the user must have a token. See the following code for reference

```
export const UserContext = createContext();


const Routing = () => {

const history = useHistory()
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)  
const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

const user = sessionStorage.getItem('token')

useEffect(() => {
if(user) {
dispatch({ type: "USER", payload: user })
} else {
history.push('/login')
}}, [])

return (
<>
     <Router>
             <Switch>
                
                {/* Give access to user even though not logged in or has token */}
                <Route exact path="/" component="Home" />

                {/* I won't let user access this Component, unless token is available  */}
                <Route exact path="/videoCall" component="VideoCall" />
             </Switch>
     </Router>
</>
)
}

const App = () => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

return (
<UserContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
       <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Routing />
         </Switch>
     </Router>
</UserContext.Provider>
)
}

export default App;
```

So, what could be the best possible solution, give access to the Home page even though not logged in, but, redirect the user to Login Page when trying to access other components like VideoCall.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help - a Router comonent of your own, which will check whether the user is authenticated and will decide whether to let him in the component or not. If you want the Home component to be rendered, just make it render, and components you don't want to be rendered if user is not logged in, just add a check in the component (or in the router component of you own) whether the user is authenticated...

BTW, every render, the `user` const is assigned the sessionstorage.getItem() value... *every render*. If you want it to happen only once, or only when a specfic variable changes - you should totally use `useMemo` (`const user = useMemo(()=>sessionStorage.getItem(), [])`) (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you suggest any changes in my code?